# Как заменить некоторые данные из dataframe на данные из series путем сопоставления индексов?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

У меня есть pd.Series `y_pred` с индексами строк в dataframe, которые я хочу заменить. Поэтому я пытаюсь заменить эти строки на

```
df_to_predict.loc[branche_condition] = df_to_predict.loc[branche_condition].replace({"stock_2021": y_pred})
```

Но dataframe остается моим модифицированным:

```
stock_2020,stock_2021,Branche
1193338.0,,1812.0
378726.0,,1812.0
88297.0,,1812.0
88297.0,,1812.0
4287508.0,,1812.0
4287508.0,,1812.0
4287508.0,,1812.0
724774.0,642650.0,1812.0
2947152.0,3219622.0,1812.0
352024.0,405613.0,1812.0
352024.0,405613.0,1812.0
889909.0,861088.0,1812.0
889909.0,861088.0,1812.0
119853.0,,1812.0
764503.0,,1812.0
1028966.0,,1812.0
709700.0,799389.0,1812.0
85619.0,231060.0,1812.0
23058.0,52859.0,1812.0
421565.0,443918.0,1812.0
1443123.0,1019643.0,1812.0
188508.0,374393.0,1812.0
121220.0,120100.0,1812.0
547485.0,,1812.0
42823.0,,1812.0
431497.0,819528.0,1812.0
2538255.0,3180496.0,1812.0
210115.0,251683.0,1812.0
5453689.0,,1812.0
5453689.0,,1812.0
5453689.0,,1812.0
5453689.0,,1812.0
89459059.0,78192209.0,1812.0
721692.0,,1812.0
205752.0,,1812.0
```

Это `y_pred`:

```
146      1.222679e+06
254      5.120698e+05
1641     2.587204e+05
1642     2.587204e+05
1857     3.921810e+06
1858     3.921810e+06
1859     3.921810e+06
3445     2.862476e+05
3698     8.485939e+05
4493     1.079292e+06
6174     6.592830e+05
7680     2.190521e+05
9632     4.939103e+06
9633     4.939103e+06
9634     4.939103e+06
9635     4.939103e+06
10298    8.112487e+05
10435    3.611797e+05
```

Итак, как изменить некоторые значения в dataframe на значения в pandas Series на основе заданных индексов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас в `y_pred` есть индексы исходного датафрейма, то всё должно быть несколько проще:

```
df_to_predict.loc[y_pred.index, "stock_2021"] = y_pred
```